# SwiftUI - How to set Voiceover Language on view basis?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, voiceover

In my SwiftUI App I have a `TextView` based on `UIViewRepresentable`. `TextView` displays text in different languages, depending on user action. All the text is always in the same language, i.e. it does not mix text of different languages at a time.

Now, I need to support VoiceOver and the problem is that `TextView`s text is always spoken in  users preferred language, which is often inappropriate. I want to set the TextView's VoiceOver language depending on its text language without affecting my other views.

How to set VoiceOver language in SwiftUI on a view basis ?

Thanks